# How to use npm installed requireJS for browser

Tags: javascript, npm, requirejs

While `requirejs` is capable of using [npm-installed modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2), how do I use `requirejs` in first place if itself is installed via `npm install requirejs`?

I have read examples of using `requirejs` listed in the [example-section](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#examples). They all seems to assume `require.js` is downloaded into a specific location. Since the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2) specifically said

> do not do something like require("./node_modules/foo/foo").

I guess it is not right to put in `index.html` something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="scripts" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the recommended way to use requirejs if it is npm-installed? If I missed something from the documentation please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you are conflating a bunch of different uses of RequireJS:

1. How can you use a RequireJS installed through Node in the browser?

   You can just install it with `npm install requirejs`, and then you have your HTML file have a `script` element that points to `node_modules/requirejs/require.js`. Exactly as you show in your code snippet. That's all there is to it. This being said, I don't like to have `node_modules` in what I deploy, so I typically have my build process copy `require.js` elsewhere.
2. How can you load npm-installed modules with RequireJS in Node?

   Suppose without RequireJS you would load the module `foo` by doing `require('foo')`. You install RequireJS and load it as `requirejs`. How do you load `foo` using RequireJS? You can just do `requirejs('foo')`. So long as RequireJS does not find it through its own configuration, it will issue as a last resort a call to Node's own `require`, and will load it this way? Here's an illustration. Install RequireJS with `npm install requirejs`. Create this file:

   ```
   var requirejs = require("requirejs");

   var fs = requirejs("fs");
   console.log(fs);
   ```

   Then run it. You'll get on the console Node's `fs` module.
3. How can you load npm-installed modules with RequireJS in a browser?

   **It depends on the modules.** RequireJS does not contain code that will magically make a npm-installed module work in the browser. It ultimately depends on how the modules are structured. Some cases:

   A. Some npm-installed modules can be loaded with RequireJS without modification. There's one library I've authored which is distributed through npm and yet is a collection of AMD modules. It is trivial to load them with RequireJS in the browser.

   B. It may require being wrapped in `define` calls. I've recently loaded [`merge-options`](https://github.com/schnittstabil/merge-options) in one of my projects with [`gulp-wrap-amd`](https://github.com/phated/gulp-wrap-amd). `merge-options` is a CommonJS module. It does not support RequireJS out-of-the-box but if you wrap it with a `define` call, it will work.

   C. It may require something more complex before it will be loaded in a browser. For instance, if a module relies on Node's `fs` module, you'll have to provide a replacement for `fs` that runs in a browser. It will presumably present a fake filesystem to your code.

Comment: Regarding your first point, is this the reason why `r.js` exists?

Comment: `r.js` exists *primarily* to optimize a bunch of modules into a single bundle. It can also be used to wrap modules that are in the CommonJS idiom with a `define` call but I've not used it for that. (And the Gulp project recommends `gulp-wrap-amd` so that's what I've used.)

Comment: On "It is trivial to load them with RequireJS in the browser" in your case A: care to give an example? Apparently I cannot get `require(['reconnecting-websocket'], function (foo) {});` to work.