# How To Use This Package Without A Bundler

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to use this package here without using any bundlers(webpack/browserify). I have already downloaded this package to my project by running `npm install --save mtgsdk`. To use this package in Javascript, I would call `const mtg = require('mtgsdk')`. If I don't want to install/configure webpack, how would I load this package into my project?

Note that I am using `Gulp` and `NPM`. My project is an AngularJS project so I am not using `node`.

Package I am trying to load: https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-javascript

Comment: what's exactly your project?

Comment: `const mtg = require('mtgsdk')`

Comment: @Shadowfact's answer is correct, that if you're using _node_, then there's no need to use webpack. However, after looking through the source code, it doesn't look like there's a straight-forward way to use it in the browser

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I am not using `node`. I am writing an AngularJS app.

Comment: http://browserify.org/ ?

Comment: @btzr - Sorry, I forgot to include in my question that Browserify as another package I do not want to be using

Comment: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: please see the last section of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409155/6836839

Comment: Just try to use the api, that module is just a wrapper, check my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick answer

You can't without using any bundlers like webpack or browserify.

Try to use [requireJs](http://requirejs.org/) however It depends on the modules:

> RequireJS does not contain code that will magically make a npm-installed module work in the browser. It ultimately depends on how the modules are structured.

To know more about this please check the last section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409155/6836839) by @Louis

#### MTG API

> The Gathering SDK Javascript implementation: It is a wrapper around the MTG API of [magicthegathering.io](https://magicthegathering.io)

I don't really see the point of using a `npm` module if you aren't going to use node in your project.

As mentioned before the module is just a wrapper for the [`api`](https://docs.magicthegathering.io/) so you can still do an http request usign the api endpoint:

```
https://api.magicthegathering.io/<version>/<resource>
```

#### Example: client.js

> This call will return a maximum of 100 cards

```
    // Get All Cards
    const api = 'https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1';
    fetch(`${api}/cards`).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

#### Output

```
{ cards: [...] }
```

To know more about the api please read the [api-docs](https://docs.magicthegathering.io/#documentationgetting_started)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Webpack to use require. Once you've run `npm install`, the package has been downloaded to the `node_modules` folder of your project. You can require the package perfectly fine from any script within your project folder. Node itself will handle finding the package in `node_modules` when you call `require`.

Comment: When I use `require`, I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Note that I am not using `node`. I am writing an AngularJS app.