# How to access require, from an HTML file, when contextIsolation is set to true

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, requirejs

I’m trying to get electron into this HTML file, but `require` is undefined:

```html
<script>
    const electron = require("electron");
    const {icpRenderer} = electron;

    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

    function submitForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const item = document.querySelector("#item").value;
    }
</script>
```

I have `nodeIntegration` as True, and `contextIsolation` as True for the web preferences which is used to prevent security warnings. How can I get `require` through this file?

---

[Full source code](https://github.com/bradtraversy/electronshoppinglist/blob/master/addWindow.html)

[Guide Video Adding Script tags](https://youtu.be/kN1Czs0m1SU?t=1762)

In `main.js`:

```js
function createAddWindow(){
    addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        title: "Add Inventory Item",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
            contextIsolation: true
        }
    });

    addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.html"),
        protocol: "file",
        slashes: true
    }));

    addWindow.on("close", function(){
        addWindow = null;
    })
}
```

Comment: Use `<script src="/path/to.electron"></script>` to use Javascript in HTML. I think you are trying to use server-side Javascript.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Electron is installed in the same directory under node modules, but every time I make the src one of those js files, I get the same error because `require` is being used in those js files.  `<script src="node_modules/electron/package.js">`

Comment: Usually, we do not need .html files for Node.js project. I don't know why you wrap your server-side Javascript code with `<script>` tag...? If it is .js file for Node.js project, remove them and try it again.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi I've edited my original post and included the github with the full code and the guide I'm following.  There's also the function I'm using to create the window I'm getting the error in. The most important part probably being the `webPreferences`; without `contextIsolation` as true, require is defined.  I'm not entirely sure why the `<script>` tags are being used.

Comment: Try `<script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405412/how-to-use-npm-installed-requirejs-for-browser). As stated, RequireJS does not contain code that will magically make a npm-installed module work in the browser. The code was written 3 years ago, so you would like to test the code first. If it works, start from there.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi That has stopped the error, but none of the `<script>` code seems to be running now.  I've tried logging to the console and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I was having was that with `contextIsolation` enabled it's not possible to use `require`.

To access `ipcRenderer` with `contextIsolation` enabled, a preload file is used with `contextBridge` to expose certain functions from `ipcRenderer`:

`preload.js`

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("myAPI", {
    ipcSend: (...args) => ipcRenderer.send(...args),

    ipcOn: (key, handler) => ipcRenderer.on(key, (event, ...args) => handler(...args))
});
```

`main.js`

```js
function createAddWindow(){
    subWindowOpen = true;
    addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        title: "Add Inventory Item",
        webPreferences: {
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    });

    addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.html"),
        protocol: "file",
        slashes: true
    }));
}
```

`addWindow.html`

```html
<script>
    myAPI.ipcSend("item:add", item);
</script>
```

`nodeIntegration` could be used instead without `contextIsolation` enabled, but this is considered to be unsafe.  It's better to expose only certain functions rather than the whole object.